# Angular 6 mouseenter is fired instead click event on tap

Tags: angular

I have simple div button with click, mouseenter and mouseleave action:

```
<div 
  class='name' 
  (click)="click($event)"
  (mouseenter)='showTooltip($event)'
  (mouseleave)='hideTooltip()'
>button</div>
```

It works perfectly fine on desktop but on iPhone I noticed that on first tap, it will fire mouseenter (hover effect) instead of click event but upon second click on the same element it will fire the click event.

I need to fire the click event on the first tap. I read that I could you (tap) instead of (click) but with this combination (click and tap together) a single click will result as double click.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave are not events designed for phones. I guess you should use (tap) instead of (click) not both. Since the (click) event doesn't works very well on phone devices but as far as I know tap will do the job.

Comment: @Osakr thanks but (tap) does not work in IE11 which is required in this case.

Comment: Then i would suggest to identify the browser and then depending on it apply an event or another